# Updating a test case result in Rally using javascript rally node module

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying to update a test case result in Rally using the node module "rally" (https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide)

This is the method i'm using:

```
rally.update({
                ref: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/'+data.TestCaseResult.TestCases, //may be a ref ('/defect/1234') or an object with a _ref property
                data: {
                    Build: data.TestCaseResult.Build, //the data with which to update the specified object
                    Verdict: data.TestCaseResult.Verdict,
                    //Owner: data.TestCaseResult.Tester,
                    Notes: data.TestCaseResult.Notes
                }
            }, function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(result.Object);
                }
            });
        }
```

And i'm sending the following object:

```
TestCaseResult:Object {Build: "SOMEBUILD", TestCases: "51741622121", Tester: "tester@tester.com" …}
Build:"SOMEBUILD"
Notes:"Some notes..."
TestCases:"51741622121"
Tester:"tester@tester.com"
Verdict:"Fail"
```

But this is what the server is giving me back:
{ [Error: /testcaseresult/53198558325: 401! body=undefined]
  errors: [ '/testcaseresult/53198558325: 401! body=undefined' ] }

This isn't a matter of API key or connection issues because prior to running an update, I run a query to get me the test case internal ID and it works just fine. I'd just like to know an example of updating a test case result in Rally using the node 'rally-node' api.

Here is how I instance rally in the code:

```
var rally = new rallyClient({
    apiKey: sails.config.services.rally.apiKey,
    apiVersion: 'v2.0',
    server: sails.config.services.rally.host,
    requestOptions: {
        proxy: 'proxy info'
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: 401 is an authentication error, so I think you will need to post the rest of your code (at least the part where you create the `rally` variable used in your example)

Comment: I use an api key to auithenticate and it works fine with other methods like getting the real ID of a TestCase and not the TC.var rally = new rallyClient({
    apiKey: sails.config.services.rally.apiKey,
    apiVersion: 'v2.0',
    server: sails.config.services.rally.host,
    requestOptions: {
        proxy: 'PROXYINFO'
    }
});

Comment: Does your api key have full access? And does the user who generated the api key have edit access to the project the test case resides?

Comment: also this line `'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/'+data.TestCaseResult.TestCases` doesn't seem like it would result in a valid ref. Can you print out the ref you are attempting to use with the update call?

Comment: @agradl, I have full access on the API key and on my user too because I am running this code on my own test case and I have permission to edit. The URL leads to this: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/53198558325

Comment: Thanks Liquidice, can you add this to the top of your file? `require('request').debug = true;` and then add the body of the request that's failing to your question? Don't forget to redact your apiKey/zsessionid!

Comment: Thanks @agradl, I stopped using the node module because I couldn't get it to work. Instead i'm just sending the information through a POST request to the /create endpoint with a JSON body. The problem i'm having is that I keep getting 401 unauthorized because I'm going through a http proxy, whilst the website is https, plus Rally is with SSO integration. For some reason I still can't get it to work. Last week I did it with postman and it worked fine but then when I tried it today, it wasn't working.